# UITabBar overlaps the navigation bar when editing items in landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm currently developing an iOS application in which I need to use a tab bar. While testing it on a small device (iPhone 4s) I found that If I rotated the device into landscape mode the title is overlapping the title bar.

Before rotation :
[image: Before rotation]

After rotation :
[image: After rotation]

Is there a way I can fix this ? I don't have acces to this view because it is managed by the UITabBar.

Comment: Are you using auto layout and constraints?

Comment: I can't edit this view, it is managed by iOS. All UITabBar comes with it.